# Eclipse "open implementation" where it resides in a superclass

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public interface Foo {
    public void bar();
}

public class FooBar {
    public void bar() {
    }
}

public class FooImpl extends FooBar implements Foo {
}

public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new FooImpl();
        foo.bar();
    }
}
```

Right click on foo.bar -> open implementation, it won't show up because the implementation is in the superclass of FooImpl.

If FooImpl is modified to implement the method directly, you can click through just fine. Or if FooBar is marked as implementing Foo it will also work.

Any setting available to change this so it can use the type hierarchy to locate the match?

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the hyperlink modifier (usually Crl/Cmd) and hover over the call with your pointer.

Comment: Hi,That doesn't work in this scenario. That is what I would like to work but it doesn't. Try the code in your IDE and see what I mean.

Comment: Not for me it doesn't: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydpvxeapvr0shod/Screenshot%20from%202013-12-19%2008%3A54%3A27.png  that is with Kepler SR1 on Linux 64